# React JS: Image size flickers on reload with object-fit: cover CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am displaying an image in a react app created using CRA. Every time I reload the webpage, the image flickers weirdly as below.

#### Image initially:

[image]

#### Image after flicker (actual requirement):

[image]

#### Code:

**styles.css:**

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**app.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import foo from './foo.jpg';

import './styles.css';

const App = () => <img src={foo} alt="foo" />;

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. The app is an injected boilerplate without any 3rd party libraries installed nor any other components apart from this image.
2. The issue above gets fixed if `object-fit: cover;` property is
   removed from stylesheet but that's required in order to prevent the image from being
   stretched/shrink weirdly just like in **initial image**.
3. If the issue is not reproducible, please keep developer console open or try changing network to any of the **3G presets**. I can reproduce with repetitive reloads easily.
4. I believe that `object-fit: cover` property doesn’t get applied to the image initially and takes few milliseconds to kick in.
5. Notice that the DOM structure doesn’t show up in developer console in **initial image**.
6. Any **alternate to the CSS property** would also be helpful.

Comment: Try making a codesandbox

Comment: @DennisVash it's not reproducible on codesandbox.

Comment: Why not? It should flicker in sandbox too

Comment: @DennisVash I believe that codesandbox doesn’t render the React App in an actual browser and what we see is just React being rendered within a div on their platform. So, if I reload codesandbox it won't work the way an actual browser would on a system. Same would be the case if I try reloading by clicking on the reload icon provided there.

Comment: Thats not how it works... You actually said you running a browser in a browser, codesandbox just renders the code you write, you can inspect it and see for yourself, moreover it has CRA starter so it exatcly simulates any machine

Comment: @DennisVash I didn’t say I'm running a browser on a browser. I just meant codesandbox can never work like an actual browser as it uses an iFrame to render React App so it won't reproduce the issue. And I'm not sure what you meant by starter. I just selected React JS over there to start off with. It would be helpful if you can help without a MCVE on sandbox :)

Comment: Strangely I can actually reproduce this, on Chromium browsers only and with bog standard HTML/CSS, no React required. As you say, it will not reproduce in an online editor. Even stranger, I can't find anything online about it.

Comment: If you are in development mode, css can be slow to update. Try building it to see what it would look like in production, where the css would be bundled already into the head

Comment: @SteveTomlin I made a build and hosted it both locally and remotely via surge, problem persists.

Comment: @lawrence-witt agreed absolutely with both of your comments.

Answer (score 11):

Having messed around with this for a good while now, I am pretty much convinced that it is a performance bug with Chromium browsers. Specifically, it seems related to the caching of images, and the optimizations that the browser makes when loading images into an `img` container with explicit height and width dimensions.

I say this because in my tests, emptying the cache before a reload will make the browser apply `object-fit` before the first paint happens. I also noticed that regardless of `object-fit` being present, cached images will be loaded into an `img` container with defined height and width a split second before `img` containers with only one or neither of these dimensions. This appears to be where the bug is occuring. The `object-fit` rule is only being applied during the second paint layer.

Maybe you can try and reproduce this with the following snippet to confirm? I've used a random placeholder image here but you might want to use a local image. If anyone can provide a more detailed explanation I'd be interested to hear it. As mentioned in the comments, this is reproducible with only HTML/CSS and network throttling, although I have found the effect to be much more pronounced in a React context:

```js
const { Fragment } = React;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
    
      <p>Object fit with two explicit dimensions</p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RN6ts8IZ4_0/600x400" className="img-fit"></img>
      
      <p>Positioned element with one explicit dimension</p>
      <div className="container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RN6ts8IZ4_0/600x400" className="img-position"></img>
      </div>
      
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

```css
.img-fit {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img-position {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Regardless, the second image in the snippet above is one possible workaround for this issue if it continues to give you grief. You choose the dimension you want to scale to on the parent container by making the `img` either 100% height or width. It can then be centred (or otherwise adjusted) with a combination of directional offset and transform. This is obviously not as dynamic as `object-fit` because you have to decide beforehand how to scale the image to get either a `cover` or `contain` effect.

Some alternative solutions include:

**1. Use a background image instead**

I've found that the `background` CSS property, which `object-fit` was ultimately derived from, does not suffer from the same bug. Use a `div` instead of an `img` tag and place the image on its background:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('path/yourimg.jpg') center / cover;
}
```

**2. Preloading (HTML)**

Another fix I found was preloading the image, which signals to the browser that it is a critical resource and should be fetched straight away. This would seem to support the idea that the issue is ultimately down to browser optimisation.

Unfortunately this doesn't really conform to React standards since you've only got one HTML page and it could easily get filled up with these links, but it works regardless. Put this in the `head`:

```
<link rel="preload" href="path/yourimage.jpg" as="image"/>
```

**3. Preloading (React)**

You can simulate a preload in React by waiting for the image's `onload` event to fire before making it visible to the user. This can be as quick and dirty as using a one-liner in the JSX with relevant classes:

```
// app.js

const App = () => <img src={foo} onLoad={e => e.target.classList.add('visible')}/>;

// index.css

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
};
```

Or if you are loading a batch of images you can wait for them all to be loaded before displaying the component/batch itself. This comes with some drawbacks with potential layout shift, and may need some optimization to handle large batches, but you get the idea:

```
import foo from 'path/foo.jpg';
import bar from 'path/bar.jpg';

const App = () => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadArray = [foo, bar].map(src => {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                const img = new Image();

                img.src = src;
                img.onload = () => res();
                img.onerror = () => rej();
            })
        });

        Promise.allSettled(loadArray).then(() => setLoaded(true));
    }, []);

    return loaded && (
        <>
            <img src={foo} alt="foo"></img>
            <img src={bar} alt="bar"></img>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you dug this deep in this issue. I'll give a thorough reading to your answer. But I did read briefly and I'd like to add that the images are not baked in the app but stored on server. So, I don't think that using `<link>` would be a good practice and moreover I'll have to add `inline style` to all the components across my app in order to supply background image to each of them which would eat up the performance. And, is there anyway to raise an issue for chromium browsers or the production build of chrome to be specific?

Comment: You are an absolute legend for this write up. I can't believe how lonely this post is. It's gold, thank you so much!

Comment: Using background image works! Thank you!
My use case:

`<div style={{ background: \`url('${imageUrl}') center / contain\`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }}></div>`